# Group a C# collection by inequality with a maximum group size using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

### Problem

I am trying to take a collection of objects and split it into multiple sub collections (using LINQ) where:

1. No sub collection contains two objects that are equal according to some arbitrary criteria (in the example it's that no two objects can have the same GroupId).
2. No sub collection has more than a maximum number of elements.
3. The number of sub collections should be minimized (each should be as full as possible while still satisfying 1 and 2).

### What have you tried?

So far I have tried using LINQ's Aggregate function, as well as [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ)'s Batch, Partition, DictinctBy, and some other functions.  None of them appear to do quite what I want though.  I also have a working solution that does not use LINQ exclusively.  I am hoping there is a fairly simple solution leveraging LINQ.

### Code sample

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U5LnEF) is an example that does not use LINQ.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var records = new List<Foo>() {
            new Foo(1, 1),
            new Foo(2, 1),
            new Foo(3, 1),
            new Foo(4, 2),
            new Foo(5, 2),
            new Foo(6, 3),
            new Foo(7, 4),
            new Foo(8, 5),
            new Foo(9, 6),
            new Foo(10, 7),
        };
        
        var groups = Group(records, 3);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < groups.Count(); ++i) {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"Group {i}: {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groups[i])}");
        }
    }
    
    public class Foo {
        public int Id;
        public int GroupId;
        
        public Foo(int id, int groupId) {
            this.Id = id;
            this.GroupId = groupId;
        }
    }

    public static List<List<Foo>> Group(IEnumerable<Foo> records, int maxGroupSize)
    {
        var rv = new List<List<Foo>>();

        foreach (var record in records) {
            bool added = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < rv.Count; ++i) {
                if (rv[i].Count < maxGroupSize && !rv[i].Any(a => a.GroupId == record.GroupId)) {
                    rv[i].Add(record);
                    added = true;
                    break;
                 }
            }
            if (!added) {
                rv.Add(new List<Foo>() { record });
            }
        }
        return rv;
    }
}
```

**I am not looking for just a more efficient implementation of the above.**  This is just an example of *a* solution.  I am looking for a solution that leverages LINQ.

Comment: What makes you think Linq would be more efficient?

Comment: Nothing necessarily. There is the delayed execution aspect although LINQ is not required for that. Mostly I do not want to reinvent the wheel and this seems like a problem that existing LINQ functionality would be able to solve but I do not know how. Also curiosity/edification.

Comment: So, you can add `yield return` and make this function lazy. For sure it should return  `IEnumerable<List<Foo>>`

Comment: *seems like a problem that existing LINQ functionality would be able to solve* - but in essence you're comparing across rows, something that LINQ usually makes harder

Comment: @caius-jard interesting, would you consider trying to use LINQ in this application an anti-pattern?  I have generally the same "feeling" that LINQ makes it hard to compare elements within the collection but I thought maybe I am just not using the right functions.  How would you solve this problem?  Just the usual suspects (foreach, dictionary, etc...)?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, I quite disagree that `yield return` would make it lazy.  Definition of lazy is not that it can return one item at a time, but rather that it can return one item at a time performing _only_ the minimum (lazy) computations necessary to get that one item, and not iota more. OP's code hard-computes the entire result-set before being able to say anything about result, as with most traditional approaches.  LINQ attempts to, if it can, to only evaluate minimally. Of course if all that it does is `.OrderBy`, then it's a whole computation, but in many cases it is not, thus lazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's doable with pure LINQ.

Without third requirement it's pretty trivial, but that one throws in a quirk.  The code below achieves all three requirements, AFAICT, and demonstration is at https://dotnetfiddle.net/hwECKG.

The comments are in the code that explain how the result is achieved.

There may be opportunities for optimization, but that's beyond the scope of the question.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var records = new List<Foo>() {
            new Foo(1, 1),
            new Foo(2, 1),
            new Foo(3, 1),
            new Foo(4, 2),
            new Foo(5, 2),
            new Foo(6, 3),
            new Foo(7, 4),
            new Foo(8, 5),
            new Foo(9, 6),
            new Foo(10, 7),
        };
        
        const int maxPerGroup = 3;
        
        var groups = records
            // Find and group all the Foo's that cannot be in the same collection.
            .GroupBy(r => r.GroupId) 
            // For each Foo with the same Group id, assign an index by its position.
            // This will be used in the next step to assign same-groupid foos to different buckets.
            .SelectMany(g => g.Select((r, i) => new {
                Bucket = i,
                Record = r
            }))
            // As mentioned above, assign phobic Foos to different buckets.
            .GroupBy(g => g.Bucket, p => p.Record)
            // Below is not *technically* necessary if `records` enumerable can be enumerated multiple times,
            // but I don't make that assumption. This converts items to an array so we can enumerate it more than once below.
            .Select(g => g.ToArray())
            // Now take each bucket and split it into members that fit and overflows, if any.
            .Select(b => new {
                Members = b.Take(maxPerGroup),
                Overflows = b.Skip(maxPerGroup)
            })
            // Via aggregation, go thru all buckets keeping them, but picking off their overflows into one signle overflow collection.
            // Further processing is actually nexted in projection argument of the aggregate since
            // aggregate wants to return a single item, and that's not what we need.
            .Aggregate(
                new { Groups = new List<IEnumerable<Foo>>(), Overflows = new Queue<Foo>()},
                (acc, next) => {
                    acc.Groups.Add(next.Members);
                    foreach(var o in next.Overflows)
                        acc.Overflows.Enqueue(o);
                    return acc;
                },
                // Here we have all buckets and a single overflow queue, now go thru each bucket and fill it up from overflow if it has any space left.
                t => t.Groups.Aggregate(
                    new { Groups = new List<IEnumerable<Foo>>(), Overflows = t.Overflows },
                    (dist, next) => {
                        var currentGroupMembers = next.ToList();
                        while (currentGroupMembers.Count() < maxPerGroup && dist.Overflows.Count > 0)
                            currentGroupMembers.Add(dist.Overflows.Dequeue());
                        dist.Groups.Add(currentGroupMembers);
                        return dist;
                    },
                    // And by the time we get here, we filled all existing buckets, but may have things left in overflow.
                    // So just chunk up overflow and add it to our list of buckets.
                    t2 => {
                        t2.Groups.AddRange(t2.Overflows.Chunk(maxPerGroup));
                        // And that returns the final result.
                        return t2.Groups;
                    }
                )
            )
            // This is not really necessary, but helps to see in memory with debugging.
            .ToArray();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < groups.Count(); ++i) {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"Group {i}: {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groups[i])}");
        }
    }
    
    public class Foo {
        public int Id;
        public int GroupId;
        
        public Foo(int id, int groupId) {
            this.Id = id;
            this.GroupId = groupId;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I should've added the following when posting it.  I tried to stay as close as possible to a reasonable interpretation of "using LINQ", meaning try to do the whole thing in a one whooping continuous LINQ chain, and doing (nearly, exception is couple of `foreach` loops that could be avoided, but in too painful way) all computation using LINQ functions.

But it can be simplified.

The greatest scary thing there is the call to `.Aggregate`, which is efficient, but scary-looking due to having to nest it inside the projection argument.  Quite easier would be to simply take the first `.Aggregate` without projection argument, and save return to a local variable.  The return there would be a single object containing Groups and single list of Overflows.  Then, you can just call `.GetEnumerator()` on overflow, and then a simple loop can easily go thru each group and "stuff it up" by consuming enumerator, and then the chunk if necessary.  That code would look shorter (albeit doing about the same thing), but might not meet OP's requirement of it being "LINQ".

Other simplifications are possible by creating LINQ extension methods to do some custom steps easily that vanilla LINQ makes it tougher.  For challenge purposes I didn't go that way, but from own experience, that can help to simplify code as well (and still be "LINQ").

Also, I should note that my demo is not meant to show "most efficient use of LINQ", but rather taking on a challenge of doing that in LINQ (that I knew is possible).  This code can probably be simplified, and I welcome anyone to take a shot at that -- I just don't have time to also make the answer solution more "elegant."

But to the comments that it's too complicated -- it depends.  We don't know why OP wants it in LINQ.  LINQ tends to get more efficient as it tends to avoid extra copying and moving of data.  Or maybe OP wants to plug it in into a larger LINQ-based infrastructure, and thus wants to get an `IEnumerable` out for more processing in the LINQ infrastructure.  I once worked on reporting-like problem where LINQ chain was generated programatically based on parameters, and resulted in 25+ transformations before it got to final answer, but it worked efficiently minimizing data copy operations and allowing it to plug in into a generic consumer of the data.

**UPDATE 2**

So here's a shorter version, but is a bit less LINQy, though still very much uses LINQ to solve the problem: https://dotnetfiddle.net/n9Fz6K

Not sure if it looks less scary or not, nor on whether which one is better performing.  But there's definitely more than one way to do this, and is possible.

LINQ takes time to get used to, and reading the code can be a bit like reading SQL -- gotta think in "set of data" rather than individual records of data.  But once you get a hang of it, it's much easer to read and understand than old-school way :D.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var records = new List<Foo>() {
            new Foo(1, 1),
            new Foo(2, 1),
            new Foo(3, 1),
            new Foo(4, 2),
            new Foo(5, 2),
            new Foo(6, 3),
            new Foo(7, 4),
            new Foo(8, 5),
            new Foo(9, 6),
            new Foo(10, 7),
        };
        
        const int maxPerGroup = 3;
        
        var groupAssigns = records
            // Find and group all the Foo's that cannot be in the same collection.
            .GroupBy(r => r.GroupId)
            // For each Foo with the same Group id, assign an index by its position.
            // This will be used in the next step to assign same-groupid foos to different buckets.
            .SelectMany(g => g.Select((r, i) => new {
                Bucket = i,
                Record = r
            }))
            // As mentioned above, assign phobic Foos to different buckets.
            .GroupBy(g => g.Bucket, p => p.Record)
            // Now take each bucket and split it into members that fit and overflows, if any.
            .Select(b => b.Chunk(maxPerGroup).ToArray())
            .Select(b => new {
                Group = b[0],
                Overflows = b.Skip(1).SelectMany(c => c)
            })
            .Aggregate(
                new { Groups = new List<List<Foo>>(), Overflows = new Queue<Foo>()},
                (acc, next) => {
                    acc.Groups.Add(next.Group.ToList());
                    foreach(var o in next.Overflows)
                        acc.Overflows.Enqueue(o);
                    return acc;
                }
            );
        var groups = groupAssigns.Groups;
        foreach(var g in groups)
        {
            while(g.Count() < maxPerGroup && groupAssigns.Overflows.Count > 0)
                g.Add(groupAssigns.Overflows.Dequeue());
        }
        groups.AddRange(groupAssigns.Overflows.Chunk(maxPerGroup).Select(c => c.ToList()));


        for (int i = 0; i < groups.Count(); ++i) {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"Group {i}: {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groups[i])}");
        }
    }
    
    public class Foo {
        public int Id;
        public int GroupId;
        
        public Foo(int id, int groupId) {
            this.Id = id;
            this.GroupId = groupId;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I upvoted because this is the single most-gnarliest Linq expression I've seen so far this month.

Comment: Wow, thanks for putting this together!  This is a very clever way to organize it, my brain hurts!  I think it is good for the most part but it seems like there is an issue with the the way the overflow records are folded back in.  It doesn't check that the group the overflow is being added into doesn't already contain a record with the same `GroupId`.  See [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pbzcCz) for an example of what I mean.  Should be an easy fix I think (famous last words).

Comment: I'm not sure if I want to upvote this, it's just so damn complicated, needlessly so. This is why we always ask if we really want to use Linq in the first place.

Comment: @kthompso, I don't think there's an issue, b/c it's prevented earlier. All `Foo` that share same `GroupId` are distributed to their individual buckets as first steps, and potential conflicts are already resolved there.  So by the time we distribute other items, we already know that they won't conflict, as their `GroupId`s didn't match to anything in the earlier steps.

Comment: @kthompso, I posted an UPDATE 2 wtih another variant of the solution.  It's less intimidating with no nested `.Aggregate` calls, so may be a bit easier to understand. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Dai, it depends, really.  It's far from more twisted and complicated I've seen and written.  Compare to SQL: Is SQL too complicated if it joins a few tables, a couple of sub-selects, and GROUPBY clauses?  If you've only done basic CRUD, such SQL statements can be intimidating.  If you worked with serious data apps that take advantage of power of SQL engines, then long, nested SQL and stored procs are not scary.  IMHO, it's simply a matter of experience and skill. I'd venture that OP's code is harder to understand to trace data flow. With LINQ you just understand how dataset is transformed.

Comment: @DavidG, see my comment to Dai: generally LINQ is more readable b/c it's more about data transforms, rather than how and where data got copied.  It also tends to be more efficient with less memory copies.  It's also easier to amend as it's not as tied to the state of various collections that traditional approach would have.  It's actually not that compliczated -- the complicated part is the requirement of how data is to be.  It takes getting used to reading and writing LINQ, just like it does to get good at say SQL.  But once you do, it's actually easier than OPs code, IMHO.

Comment: +1 to @LB2. In genera, LINQ or even lambdas, to be more precise, are welcome because they then the code is more declarative (i.e., what?), not imperative (how?). In cases when there is a lot of chaining, those things could be extracted into separate methods. It was especially indicated by the usage of comments to explain those blocks.

Comment: "[Linq] tend to be more efficient with less memory copies" - I'd like to see a source on that. Especially in the 'Linq' you have given here since you're generating multiple in-memory lists, arrays, intermediate anonymous types and even queues.  As for being more readable, your code is longer than OPs code, that's just simply not true.

Comment: Sure, here's a random [SO post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/215880/127873) on that. Not saying that _every_ case is magically better, but in general that's why LINQ was engineered in the first place AFAIK.  Yes, here is a complex problem and so any approach will be non-trivial.  I haven't looked at perf closely (so could be wrong, no time, sorry), but did you notice, though, that OPs algorithm has loop inside a loop, where's LINQ would be a fixed number of passes regardless of N?

Comment: @KarlisFersters, precisely the declarative vs imperative is what I meant earlier by "LINQ easier to read".  You see how the dataset is being _transformed_, rather than tracing where some piece of data is being written to and picked up later.